# Criterion for the existence of roots of a system of polynomial equations on a torus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, torus

Given a system of polynomial equations in $n$ indeterminates $z_{1}%
,\ldots,z_{n}$:
\begin{align*}
p_{1}\left(  z_{1},\ldots,z_{n}\right)    & =0\\
& \vdots\\
p_{m}\left(  z_{1},\ldots,z_{n}\right)    & =0
\end{align*}

Is there a procedure to decide (without computing) if this system has a root
in the torus $\mathbb{T}^{n}=\left\{  z\in\mathbb{C}^{n}:\left\vert
z\right\vert =1\right\}  $?

Comment: Wouldn't a torus be $\mathbb{T}^{n}=\left\{  z\in\mathbb{C}^{n}:\left\vert z_1\right\vert =1, \ldots, \left\vert z_n\right\vert =1\right\}$? I think $|z|=1$ defines a sphere. In any case, you can adjoin more polynomial equations in $z_i, \bar{z}_i$, which cut out your desired $\mathbb{T}^n$, to get a larger real polynomial system. If there's nothing special about the original system, then I suspect your problem is as hard as checking whether a real polynomial system has any real solutions.

Comment: How does one make "procedure to decide (without computing)" precise?